# Docker container can't connect to other host

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-container, bridge, docker-network

I have one Docker project (ASP.net web app), that wants to connect to a SQL database on another server, but its connection fails. I tried to get a ping (e.g.: google.com), but it doesn't even give a ping. I have this container in Windows and all thing work correct, but on Linux server, nothing works. For mapping, in Linux I use Nginx and map it to the Docker port. I restarted Docker Network and Docker, but it's not working. I found some tips for connecting to an internal server, but my SQL is on another server. I use 5.4.0-165-generic Ubuntu.

Comment: Please Share Dockerfile or docker-compose.yaml so that anyone can understand your query better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to docker.override.yml and it now works.

```yaml
dns:
  - "8.8.8.8"

network_mode: bridge
```

My docker file is now like this

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - /path/to/local/dаta:/root/redis
      - /path/to/local/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=my-password
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - REDIS_DATABASES=16

    presentation:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "6060:80"


  user.presentation:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "6065:80"
    dns:
      - "8.8.8.8"
    network_mode: bridge
  club.apigateway:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "7055:80"
```